# CPU Clock Cycle in C#

Tags: c#, cpu, clock

in C/C++ we have a function clock() for keeping the current CPU clock for counting the time of execution programs:

```
t1 = clock()
for(...)
  for(...)
t2 = clock()
printf (t2 - t1)
```

but how I can do it in C#?
I know there is some codes:

```
long t1 = stopwatch.startnow()
for(...)
  for(...)
t1.stop()
sum = t1.elapsedticks;
```

---

The problem is, that when I run codes in C, I see about 20 ticks, but when I run the same code in C#, I see about 60000 ticks.
Please tell me that is it OK or not?
Is my solution is true? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is ok.. because C# a high level programming language and C/C++ is low programming languag..

Comment: It's almost definitely to do with what you've got in your for loops (the part you've omitted)

Comment: Side note: make sure that "ticks" are the same between C/C#... Also common problem with such benchmarks is inlining/dead code elimination performed by C/C++ compilers - there is a good chance you've measured length of empty operation in you C sample code.